# norwegian laguage localization not working in AWS (linux) with net core 2.1

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, localization, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm running in some problem trying to run my tests on Amazon web services.

First of all, mention that the test passes either in my local machine as in Teamcity (windows), but once I build it to Amazon Codebuild (Linux) is not.

In addition, the test only fails with Norwegian, I tried to add, Spanish (`"es"`), English, and french and they work properly.

I have my `Resources` folder with the files `*.es.resx`, `*.resx`, `*.en.resx`, `*.no.resx`, some more.

To get the localization I've created a helper method

```
public class TestLanguageBase<T>
{
    protected StringLocalizer<T> GetLocalizer()
    {
        IOptions<LocalizationOptions> options = Options.Create(new LocalizationOptions());
        ResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory factory = new ResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory(options, NullLoggerFactory.Instance);
        return new StringLocalizer<T>(factory);
    }
}
```

Then in the test which extends `TestLanguageBase` I execute the next

```
[Fact]
public void Test_NorwegianLanguage()
{
    CultureInfo NorweiganCulture = new CultureInfo("no");
    using (new CultureScope(NorweiganCulture))
    {
        var localizer = GetLocalizer();
        var result = localizer["LanguageChecker"];
        Assert.Equal("NorwegianLanguage", result);
    }
}
```

Edit: I tried with `nb` and seems to be working. but why is the reason for?
do I need to create two different `.resx` files for the same language?

the Spanish test works with no problem.

```
[Fact]
public void Test_Spanish()
{
    CultureInfo spanishCulture = new CultureInfo("es");
    using (new CultureScope(spanishCulture))
    {
        var localizer = GetLocalizer();
        var result = localizer["LanguageChecker"];
        Assert.Equal("SpanishLanguage", result);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know if there is any difference between Windows and Linux in this kind of aspect?

Thanks.

Comment: We had the same issue in our organisation. Because the translations were automated, we could just do a simple copy command: cp ./LanguageFile.no.resx ./LanguageFile.nn.resx and use both files in production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux prefers the "nn" language code for Norwegian, instead of the "no" code